# How do I convert a trackball mouse into a 360° scroller?

Tags: xorg

Is it possible to use the ball of a trackball mouse as a 360° scroller (or a 2D mouse wheel)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very nice solution for my question and thought others might be interested. It works on any mouse not just trackballs.

open or create the file `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf` and add the following section:

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier  "Mouse0"
   Driver "evdev"
   MatchIsPointer "on"
   MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"

   Option "EmulateWheel" "true"
   Option "EmulateWheelButton" "9"

   Option "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
   Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
EndSection
```

Logout and relogin or restart. Now by pressing button #9 you can use the trackball (or mouse) as a 360° scroller. Very handy for photo editing for example.